# How (or why) do i find negative cycles with Johnson's algorithm

Tags: shortest-path

The first step of Johnson's algorithm is the creation of a new vertex s which has an edge to every other vertex with a weight of 0.
Then I perform only one iteration of the Bellman-Ford algorithm on this new graph and with this one iteration, you can see if there are negative cycles in this graph. But why is that?
When you do the Bellman-Ford algorithm you usually do v-1 iterations to find the solution and when you do another iteration and there is still a change in the distance table you know that there must be a negative cycle, right?
How can you see if there is a negative cycle with only one iteration of Bellman-Ford?

Comment: From my knowledge, bellman form does require $|C|$ iterations (where $C$ is the set of vertices in the negative cycle) to find a negative cycle. I never saw such a claim that states with only one iteration of bellman ford you can find negative cycles...

Comment: Yeah when you do Bellman-Ford itself, but in Johnson's algorith you only do one iteration of Bellman-Ford before reweighting or did i get this wrong? When you do as many Iterations of Bellman-Ford in Johnson's Algorithm as you do in Bellman-Ford itself, how can Johnson's be faster than Bellma-Ford?

Comment: I think they meant a full run of the bellman-ford algorithm *once*.

Comment: Take a look in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yeah in the Algorithm Description it says ```the Bellman–Ford algorithm is used, starting from the new vertex q, to find for each vertex v the minimum weight h(v) of a path from q to v``` so i guess you're right and it is a full run of Bellman-Ford, but i don't get why this can be faster than a usual Bellman-Ford run, but i guess that is due to the weight of 0 at each edge

Comment: This wont be faster than the usual bellman ford run. When you look at the running time analysis of Johnson's algorithm, you see there is a factor of $|V||E|$ for the bellman-ford algorithm

Comment: In my Lecture i learned that Johnson's algorithm is so nice because, it combines the strength of Dijkstra (being fast) and the strength of Bellman-Ford (being able to run on graphs with negative edge weight). When The Bellman-Ford Part at the beginning of Johnson's is as slow as usual Bellman-Ford, why would you ever use Johnson's algorithm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124899/discussion-between-nir-shahar-and-lxg95).